# Getting an error after changing package name

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, package

I'm getting an error after changing the package name, but when set it back to the old package name the app compiles normally without any problems
The Error:

- Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your build?

Comment: Yes but i'm still getting this error

Comment: How did you change the package name, exactly?  I did this a couple of months ago, and it is imperative that you change ALL references to your package all over the project.  That would include every single import in every single file, the Manifest, any layout that reference custom Views, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**You may missed the 3rd step.**

1- First open AndroidManifest.xml. Select the part of your package name in the package property that you want to change.

2- Right-click with the mouse on the part of your package name you want to change. In the menu that appears, choose Refactor > Rename. The Warning window will open. In this window, select the Rename package button. When you select this bot, the Rename window will open. Change the name and select the Refactor button.

3- Finally open the `build.gradle` file in the main directory->app folder. In this file, change the package name in the applicationId property and press the Sync Now button to save the change.

I don't have a problem when I follow these steps. I hope that will be useful.

Comment: Same here,  it's usually a cure all. I will add that sometimes you might run into a android studio version issue but that is rare